# Stuck on boolean algebra problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could someone please explain me why

$x.y+x.z+y'.z$

Is equal to

$x.y+y'.z$?

I just can't simplificate it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x.y+x.z+y'.z$

$=x.y+x.z.1+y'z$ [as,$a.1=a$]

$=x.y+x.z.(y+y')+y'z$ [as $(a+a')=1$]

$=x.y+x.z.y+x.z.y'+y'z$

$=x.y(1+z)+y'z(x+1)$

$=(x.y+y'z)$ [as $(a+1)=1$]

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Yes this helps a lot thanks! So actually in xyz is xy = xyz + xyz'. I have learned about this in functions but I didn't think of using it anywhere else

Comment: Yes you can see line 2,3 how this is applied